# Delayed outgoing mail in active queue

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I am stuck for some time trying to set up an email server. I've been mostly successful in my setup, but I am currently stuck at the following impasse: **every time** I send an email (regardless of queue size), my message will get stuck in the active queue for ~ 5 minutes, after which it will **always** be sent and reach it's final destination.

```
postqueue -p
```

(shows only one mail in the queue)

```
postqueue -f
```

... has no effect

I am running postfix 3.1.0, and dovecot 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 16.04. Also, I used iRedMail scripts for the installation. I can see from /var/log/mail.log that the mail is being stored in a queue by postfix, and I'm assuming there's another setting to set the time at which it will be processed. Any help would be most appreciated.

/var/log/mail.log

> Jan  9 14:35:28 mail postfix[26070]: name_mask: all
>
> Jan  9 14:35:28 mail postfix[26070]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
>
> Jan  9 14:35:28 mail postfix[26070]: inet_addr_local: configured 3 IPv6 addresses
>
> Jan  9 14:35:28 mail postfix/postfix-script[26075]: error: unknown command: ''
>
> Jan  9 14:35:28 mail postfix/postfix-script[26076]: fatal: usage: postfix start (or stop, reload, abort, flush, check, status, set-permissions, upgrade-configuration)
>
> Jan  9 14:35:49 mail postfix[26085]: fatal: usage: postfix [-c config_dir] [-Dv] command
>
> Jan  9 14:35:58 mail postfix[26090]: fatal: usage: postfix [-c config_dir] [-Dv] command
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[26282]: connect from mail.example.com[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[26282]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail.example.com[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[26282]: 87ABB42362: client=mail.example.com[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=jamal@example.com
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/cleanup[26288]: 87ABB42362: message-id=<0130a1e7b419fdf0f31ce406618aef97@example.com>
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/qmgr[28474]: 87ABB42362: from=, size=1845, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jan  9 14:40:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[26282]: disconnect from mail.example.com[127.0.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
>
> Jan  9 14:45:05 mail amavis[10642]: (10642-08) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: run_av error: ask_daemon_internal: Exceeded allowed time at (eval 104) line 611.\n
>
> Jan  9 14:45:05 mail amavis[10642]: (10642-08) (!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
>
> Jan  9 14:45:05 mail amavis[10642]: (10642-08) (!!)AV: ALL VIRUS SCANNERS FAILED
>
> Jan  9 14:45:07 mail postfix/postqueue[26446]: fatal: usage: postqueue -f | postqueue -i queueid | postqueue -j | postqueue -p | postqueue -s site
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[26452]: connect from mail.example.com[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[26452]: 60ADA423BA: client=mail.example.com[127.0.0.1]
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/cleanup[26454]: 60ADA423BA: message-id=<0130a1e7b419fdf0f31ce406618aef97@example.com>
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/10025/smtpd[26452]: disconnect from mail.example.com[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/qmgr[28474]: 60ADA423BA: from=, size=2920, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail amavis[10642]: (10642-08) Passed UNCHECKED {RelayedInternal}, ORIGINATING/MYNETS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:33748  -> , Queue-ID: 87ABB42362, Message-ID: <0130a1e7b419fdf0f31ce406618aef97@example.com>, mail_id: FFIMhQZ3j_4G, Hits: 0.204, size: 1845, queued_as: 60ADA423BA, dkim_new=dkim:example.com, 290782 ms, Tests: [ALL_TRUSTED=-1,HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,TVD_RCVD_SINGLE=1.213,T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD=-0.01]
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/amavis/smtp[26293]: 87ABB42362: to=, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=291, delays=0.16/0.03/0.04/291, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 60ADA423BA)
>
> Jan  9 14:45:08 mail postfix/qmgr[28474]: 87ABB42362: removed
>
> Jan  9 14:45:09 mail postfix/smtp[26455]: Untrusted TLS connection established to cornellprod-mail-onmicrosoft-com.mail.eo.outlook.com[216.32.181.106]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
>
> Jan  9 14:45:09 mail postfix/smtp[26455]: 60ADA423BA: to=, relay=cornellprod-mail-onmicrosoft-com.mail.eo.outlook.com[216.32.181.106]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.02/0.03/0.64/0.89, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <0130a1e7b419fdf0f31ce406618aef97@example.com> [InternalId=132499741090511, Hostname=BN3PR0401MB1284.namprd04.prod.outlook.com] 10597 bytes in 0.347, 29.819 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
>
> Jan  9 14:45:09 mail postfix/qmgr[28474]: 60ADA423BA: removed
>
> Jan  9 14:45:20 mail postfix/postqueue[26468]: fatal: Flush service is not configured for destination "active"

/etc/postfix/main.cf

> # --------------------
>   # INSTALL-TIME CONFIGURATION INFORMATION
>   #
>   # location of the Postfix queue. Default is /var/spool/postfix. queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
>
> # location of all postXXX commands. Default is /usr/sbin. command_directory = /usr/sbin
>
> # location of all Postfix daemon programs (i.e. programs listed in the
>   # master.cf file). This directory must be owned by root.
>   # Default is /usr/libexec/postfix daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix/sbin
>
> # location of Postfix-writable data files (caches, random numbers).
>   # This directory must be owned by the mail_owner account (see below).
>   # Default is /var/lib/postfix. data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
>
> # owner of the Postfix queue and of most Postfix daemon processes.
>   # Specify the name of a user account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID
>   # WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.
>   # In particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED USER.
>   # Default is postfix. mail_owner = postfix
>
> # The following parameters are used when installing a new Postfix version.
>   #
>   # sendmail_path: The full pathname of the Postfix sendmail command.
>   # This is the Sendmail-compatible mail posting interface.
>   # sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
>
> # newaliases_path: The full pathname of the Postfix newaliases command.
>   # This is the Sendmail-compatible command to build alias databases.
>   # newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
>
> # full pathname of the Postfix mailq command.  This is the Sendmail-compatible
>   # mail queue listing command. mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
>
> # group for mail submission and queue management commands.
>   # This must be a group name with a numerical group ID that is not shared with
>   # other accounts, not even with the Postfix account. setgid_group = postdrop
>
> # debugger_command =
>       PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
>       ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
>
> debug_peer_level = 2
>
> # --------------------
>   # CUSTOM SETTINGS
>   #
>
> # SMTP server response code when recipient or domain not found. unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
>
> # Do not notify local user. biff = no
>
> # Disable the rewriting of "site!user" into "user@site". swap_bangpath = no
>
> # Disable the rewriting of the form "user%domain" to "user@domain". allow_percent_hack = no
>
> # Allow recipient address start with '-'. allow_min_user = no
>
> # Disable the SMTP VRFY command. This stops some techniques used to
>   # harvest email addresses. disable_vrfy_command = yes
>
> # Enable both IPv4 and/or IPv6: ipv4, ipv6, all. inet_protocols = all
>
> # Enable all network interfaces. inet_interfaces = all
>
> #
>   # TLS settings.
>   #
>   # SSL key, certificate, CA
>   # smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
>   smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem
>   smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem
>
> #
>   # Disable SSLv2, SSLv3
>   # smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
>   smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3 lmtp_tls_protocols =
>   !SSLv2 !SSLv3 lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
>
> #
>   # Fix 'The Logjam Attack'.
>   # smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDC3-SHA, KRB5-DE5,
>   CBC3-SHA smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh512_param.pem
>   smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem
>
> tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
>
> smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
>
> # Opportunistic TLS: announce STARTTLS support to remote SMTP clients, but do
>   # not require that clients use TLS encryption. smtpd_tls_security_level = may
>
> # Produce `Received:` message headers that include information about the
>   # protocol and cipher used, as well as the remote SMTP client CommonName and
>   # client certificate issuer CommonName.
>   # This is disabled by default, as the information may be modified in transit
>   # through other mail servers. Only information that was recorded by the final
>   # destination can be trusted.
>   #smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
>
> # Opportunistic TLS, used when Postfix sends email to remote SMTP server.
>   # Use TLS if this is supported by the remote SMTP server, otherwise use
>   # plaintext.
>   # References:
>   #   - http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#client_tls_may
>   #   - http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_security_level smtp_tls_security_level = may
>
> # Use the same CA file as smtpd. smtp_tls_CAfile = $smtpd_tls_CAfile smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
>
> # Enable long, non-repeating, queue IDs (queue file names).
>   # The benefit of non-repeating names is simpler logfile analysis and easier
>   # queue migration (there is no need to run "postsuper" to change queue file
>   # names that don't match their message file inode number).
>   #enable_long_queue_ids = yes
>
> # Reject unlisted sender and recipient smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
>
> # Header and body checks with PCRE table header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks body_checks =
>   pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks.pcre
>
> # A mechanism to transform commands from remote SMTP clients.
>   # This is a last-resort tool to work around client commands that break
>   # interoperability with the Postfix SMTP server. Other uses involve fault
>   # injection to test Postfix's handling of invalid commands.
>   # Requires Postfix-2.7+.
>   #smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre
>
> # HELO restriction smtpd_helo_required = yes smtpd_helo_restrictions =
>       permit_mynetworks
>       permit_sasl_authenticated
>       check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
>       reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
>       reject_unknown_helo_hostname
>
> # Sender restrictions smtpd_sender_restrictions =
>       reject_unknown_sender_domain
>       reject_non_fqdn_sender
>       reject_unlisted_sender
>       permit_mynetworks
>       permit_sasl_authenticated
>       check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access.pcre
>
> # Recipient restrictions smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
>       reject_unknown_recipient_domain
>       reject_non_fqdn_recipient
>       reject_unlisted_recipient
>       check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
>       permit_mynetworks
>       permit_sasl_authenticated
>       reject_unauth_destination
>
> # END-OF-MESSAGE restrictions smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
>       check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777
>
> # Data restrictions smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
>
> proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps
>   $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps
>   $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps
>   $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps
>   $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps
>   $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains
>   $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
>   $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
>
> # Avoid duplicate recipient messages. Default is 'yes'. enable_original_recipient = no
>
> # Virtual support. virtual_minimum_uid = 2000 virtual_uid_maps = static:2000 virtual_gid_maps = static:2000 virtual_mailbox_base =
>   /var/vmail
>
> # Do not set virtual_alias_domains. virtual_alias_domains =
>
> #
>   # Enable SASL authentication on port 25 and force TLS-encrypted SASL authentication.
>   # WARNING: NOT RECOMMENDED to enable smtp auth on port 25, all end users should
>   #          be forced to submit email through port 587 instead.
>   #
>   #smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
>   #smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
>   #smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
>
> # hostname myhostname = mail.example.com myorigin = mail.example.com mydomain = mail.example.com
>
> # trusted SMTP clients which are allowed to relay mail through Postfix.
>   #
>   # Note: additional IP addresses/networks listed in mynetworks should be listed
>   #       in iRedAPD setting 'MYNETWORKS' (in `/opt/iredapd/settings.py`) too.
>   #       for example:
>   #
>   #       MYNETWORKS = ['xx.xx.xx.xx', 'xx.xx.xx.0/24', ...]
>   # mynetworks = 127.0.0.1 [::1]
>
> # Accepted local emails mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
>
> alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases alias_database =
>   hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
>
> # Default message_size_limit. message_size_limit = 15728640
>
> # The set of characters that can separate a user name from its extension
>   # (example: user+foo), or a .forward file name from its extension (example:
>   # .forward+foo).
>   # Postfix 2.11 and later supports multiple characters. recipient_delimiter = +
>
> # The time after which the sender receives a copy of the message headers of
>   # mail that is still queued. Default setting is disabled (0h) by Postfix.
>   #delay_warning_time = 1h compatibility_level = 2
>   #
>   # Lookup virtual mail accounts
>   # transport_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
>
> sender_dependent_relayhost_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_dependent_relayhost_maps.cf
>
> # Lookup table with the SASL login names that own the sender (MAIL FROM) addresses. smtpd_sender_login_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
>
> virtual_mailbox_domains =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
>
> relay_domains =
>       $mydestination
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
>
> virtual_mailbox_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
>
> virtual_alias_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
>
> sender_bcc_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
>
> recipient_bcc_maps =
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf
>       proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
>
> #
>   # Postscreen
>   # postscreen_greet_action = enforce postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce postscreen_dnsbl_threshold =
>   2 postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
>       zen.spamhaus.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*3
>       b.barracudacentral.org=127.0.0.[2..11]*2
>
> postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map =
>   texthash:/etc/postfix/postscreen_dnsbl_reply postscreen_access_list =
>   permit_mynetworks cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_access.cidr
>
> # Require Postfix-2.11+ postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -2
>   #
>   # Dovecot SASL support.
>   # smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth virtual_transport = dovecot dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
>
> #
>   # Amavisd + SpamAssassin + ClamAV
>   # content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
>
> # Concurrency per recipient limit. smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

> # More details about Dovecot settings: #   -
>   http://wiki2.dovecot.org/ #   - http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables
>
> # Listen addresses. #   - '*' means all available IPv4 addresses. #
>   - '[::]' means all available IPv6 addresses. # Listen on all available addresses by default listen = * [::]
>
> #base_dir = /var/run/dovecot mail_plugins = quota mailbox_alias acl
>   mail_log notify
>
> # Enabled mail protocols. protocols = pop3 imap sieve lmtp
>
> # User/group who owns the message files: mail_uid = 2000 mail_gid =
>   2000
>
> # Assign uid to virtual users. first_valid_uid = 2000 last_valid_uid
>   = 2000
>
> # Logging. Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Logging # # Use
>   syslog syslog_facility = local5 # Log file path if we use internal
>   log system #log_path = /var/log/dovecot/dovecot.log
>
> # Debug #mail_debug = yes #auth_verbose = yes #auth_debug = yes
>   #auth_debug_passwords = yes # Possible values: no, plain, sha1.
>   #auth_verbose_passwords = no
>
> # SSL: Global settings. # Refer to wiki site for per protocol, ip,
>   server name SSL settings: #
>   http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration ssl_protocols =
>   !SSLv2 !SSLv3 ssl = required verbose_ssl = no #ssl_ca =
>
> # Fix 'The Logjam Attack' ssl_cipher_list =
>   ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5
>   # Dovecot 2.2.6 or greater: # Specify the wanted DH parameters
>   length ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
>
> # With disable_plaintext_auth=yes AND ssl=required, STARTTLS is
>   mandatory. # Set disable_plaintext_auth=no AND ssl=yes to allow plain
>   password transmitted # insecurely. disable_plaintext_auth = yes
>
> # Allow plain text password per IP address/net #remote
>   192.168.0.0/24 { #   disable_plaintext_auth = no #}
>
> # Mail location and mailbox format. mail_location =
>   maildir:%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%Lh/Maildir/
>
> # Authentication related settings. # Append this domain name if
>   client gives empty realm. #auth_default_realm = example.com
>
> # Authentication mechanisms. auth_mechanisms = PLAIN LOGIN
>
> # Limits the number of users that can be logging in at the same time.
>   # Default is 100. This can be overridden by `process_limit =` in #
>   `service [protocol]` block. # e.g. #       protocol imap-login { # 
>   ... #           process_limit = 500 #       }
>   #default_process_limit = 100
>
> service auth {
>       unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
>           user = postfix
>           group = postfix
>           mode = 0666
>       }
>       unix_listener auth-master {
>           user = vmail
>           group = vmail
>           mode = 0666
>       }
>       unix_listener auth-userdb {
>           user = vmail
>           group = vmail
>           mode = 0660
>       } }
>
> # LMTP server (Local Mail Transfer Protocol). # Reference:
>   http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LMTP service lmtp {
>       user = vmail
>
> ```
> \# For higher volume sites, it may be desirable to increase the number of
> \# active listener processes. A range of 5 to 20 is probably good for most
> \# sites.
> process_min_avail = 5
>
> \# Logging.
> \# Require 'log_path =' in 'protocol lmtp {}' block.
> executable = lmtp -L
>
> \# Listening on socket file and TCP
> unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
>     user = postfix
>     group = postfix
>     mode = 0600
> }
>
> inet_listener lmtp {
>     \# Listen on localhost (ipv4)
>     address = 127.0.0.1
>     port = 24
> } }
> ```
>
> # Virtual mail accounts. userdb {
>       args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
>       driver = sql } passdb {
>       args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-mysql.conf
>       driver = sql }
>   auth_master_user_separator = * passdb {
>       driver = passwd-file
>       args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-master-users
>       master = yes }
>
> plugin {
>       # Quota configuration.
>       # Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Quota/Configuration
>       quota = dict:user::proxy::quotadict
>       quota_rule = *:storage=1G
>       #quota_rule2 = *:messages=0
>       #quota_rule3 = Trash:storage=1G
>       #quota_rule4 = Junk:ignore
>
> ```
> \# Quota warning.
> \#
> \# If user suddenly receives a huge mail and the quota jumps from
> \# 85% to 95%, only the 95% script is executed.
> \#
> \# Only the command for the first exceeded limit is executed, so configure
> \# the highest limit first.
> quota_warning = storage=100%% quota-warning 100 %u
> quota_warning2 = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
> quota_warning3 = storage=90%% quota-warning 90 %u
> quota_warning4 = storage=85%% quota-warning 85 %u
>
> \# allow user to become max 10% (or 50 MB) over quota
> quota_grace = 10%%
> \#quota_grace = 50 M
>
> \# Custom Quota Exceeded Message.
> \# You can specify the message directly or read the message from a file.
> \#quota_exceeded_message = Quota exceeded, please try again later.
> \#quota_exceeded_message = </path/to/quota_exceeded_message.txt
>
> \# Plugin: expire.
> \#expire = Trash 7 Trash/* 7 Junk 30
> \#expire_dict = proxy::expire
>
> \# ACL and share folder
> acl = vfile
> acl_shared_dict = proxy::acl
>
> \# By default Dovecot doesn't allow using the IMAP "anyone" or
> \# "authenticated" identifier, because it would be an easy way to spam
> \# other users in the system. If you wish to allow it,
> \#acl_anyone = allow
>
> \# Pigeonhole managesieve service.
> \# Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Configuration
> \# Per-user sieve settings.
> sieve_dir = %Lh/sieve
> sieve = %Lh/sieve/dovecot.sieve
>
> \# Global sieve settings.
> sieve_global_dir = /var/vmail/sieve
> \# Note: if user has personal sieve script, global sieve rules defined in
> \#       sieve_default will be ignored. Please use sieve_before or
> \#       sieve_after instead.
> \#sieve_default =
>
> sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/dovecot.sieve
> \#sieve_after =
>
> \# The maximum number of redirect actions that can be performed during a
> \# single script execution.
> \# The meaning of 0 differs based on your version. For pigeonhole-0.3.0 and
> \# beyond this means that redirect is prohibited. For older versions,
> \# however, this means that the number of redirects is unlimited.
> sieve_max_redirects = 30
>
> \# Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/MailboxAlias
> mailbox_alias_old = Sent
> mailbox_alias_new = Sent Messages
> mailbox_alias_old2 = Sent
> mailbox_alias_new2 = Sent Items
>
> \# Events to log. `autoexpunge` is included in `expunge`
> \# Defined in https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/master/src/plugins/mail-log/mail-log-plugin.c
> mail_log_events = delete undelete expunge mailbox_delete mailbox_rename
> mail_log_fields = uid box msgid size from subject }
> ```
>
> service quota-warning {
>       executable = script /usr/local/bin/dovecot-quota-warning.sh
>       unix_listener quota-warning {
>           user = vmail
>           group = vmail
>           mode = 0660
>       } }
>
> service dict {
>       unix_listener dict {
>           mode = 0660
>           user = vmail
>           group = vmail
>       } }
>
> dict {
>       #expire = db:/var/lib/dovecot/expire/expire.db
>       quotadict = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-used-quota.conf
>       acl = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-share-folder.conf }
>
> protocol lda {
>       # Reference: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA
>       mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
>       lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
>       lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
>       postmaster_address = root
>
> ```
> \# Log file path if we use internal log system
> \#log_path = /var/log/dovecot/sieve.log }
> ```
>
> protocol lmtp {
>       # Log file path if we use internal log system
>       #log_path = /var/log/dovecot/lmtp.log
>
> ```
> \# Plugins
> mail_plugins = quota sieve
> postmaster_address = postmaster
>
> \# Address extension delivery
> lmtp_save_to_detail_mailbox = yes
> recipient_delimiter = + }
> ```
>
> protocol imap {
>       mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_quota imap_acl
>       imap_client_workarounds = tb-extra-mailbox-sep
>
> ```
> \# Maximum number of IMAP connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
> \# NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
> \# Default is 10.
> \# Increase it to avoid issue like below:
> \# "Maximum number of concurrent IMAP connections exceeded"
> mail_max_userip_connections = 30 }
> ```
>
> protocol pop3 {
>       mail_plugins = $mail_plugins
>       pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
>       pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
>
> ```
> \# Maximum number of IMAP connections allowed for a user from each IP address.
> \# NOTE: The username is compared case-sensitively.
> \# Default is 10.
> mail_max_userip_connections = 30
>
> \# POP3 logout format string:
> \#  %i - total number of bytes read from client
> \#  %o - total number of bytes sent to client
> \#  %t - number of TOP commands
> \#  %p - number of bytes sent to client as a result of TOP command
> \#  %r - number of RETR commands
> \#  %b - number of bytes sent to client as a result of RETR command
> \#  %d - number of deleted messages
> \#  %m - number of messages (before deletion)
> \#  %s - mailbox size in bytes (before deletion)
> \# Default format doesn't have 'in=%i, out=%o'.
> \#pop3_logout_format = top=%t/%p, retr=%r/%b, del=%d/%m, size=%s, in=%i, out=%o }
> ```
>
> # Login processes. Refer to Dovecot wiki for more details: #
>   http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LoginProcess service imap-login {
>       #inet_listener imap {
>       #    port = 143
>       #}
>       #inet_listener imaps {
>       #    port = 993
>       #    ssl = yes
>       #}
>
> ```
> service_count = 1
>
> \# To avoid startup latency for new client connections, set process_min_avail
> \# to higher than zero. That many idling processes are always kept around
> \# waiting for new connections.
> \#process_min_avail = 0
>
> \# number of simultaneous IMAP connections
> process_limit = 500
>
> \# vsz_limit should be fine at its default 64MB value
> \#vsz_limit = 64M }
> ```
>
> service pop3-login {
>       #inet_listener pop3 {
>       #    port = 110
>       #}
>       #inet_listener pop3s {
>       #    port = 995
>       #    ssl = yes
>       #}
>
> ```
> service_count = 1
>
> \# number of simultaneous POP3 connections
> \#process_limit = 500 }
> ```
>
> service managesieve-login {
>       inet_listener sieve {
>           # Listen on localhost (ipv4)
>           address = 127.0.0.1
>           port = 4190
>       } }
>
> namespace {
>       type = private
>       separator = /
>       prefix =
>       inbox = yes
>
> ```
> \# Refer to document for more details about alias mailbox:
> \# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings
> \#
> \# Sent
> mailbox Sent {
>     auto = subscribe
>     special_use = \Sent
> }
> mailbox "Sent Messages" {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Sent
> }
> mailbox "Sent Items" {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Sent
> }
>
> mailbox Drafts {
>     auto = subscribe
>     special_use = \Drafts
> }
>
> \# Trash
> mailbox Trash {
>     auto = subscribe
>     special_use = \Trash
> }
>
> mailbox "Deleted Messages" {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Trash
> }
>
> \# Junk
> mailbox Junk {
>     auto = subscribe
>     special_use = \Junk
> }
> mailbox Spam {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Junk
> }
> mailbox "Junk E-mail" {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Junk
> }
>
> \# Archive
> mailbox Archive {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Archive
> }
> mailbox Archives {
>     auto = no
>     special_use = \Archive
> } }
> ```
>
> namespace {
>       type = shared
>       separator = /
>       prefix = Shared/%%u/
>       location = maildir:%%Lh/Maildir/:INDEX=%%Lh/Maildir/Shared/%%Ld/%%Ln
>
> ```
> \# this namespace should handle its own subscriptions or not.
> subscriptions = yes
> list = children }
> ```
>
> # Public mailboxes. # Refer to Dovecot wiki page for more details:
>   # http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SharedMailboxes/Public #namespace { #
>   type = public #    separator = / #    prefix = Public/ #
>   location =
>   maildir:/var/vmail/public:CONTROL=%Lh/Maildir/public:INDEXPVT=%Lh/Maildir/public
>   # #    # Allow users to subscribe to the public folders. #
>   subscriptions = yes #}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ClamAV hangs and times out after 5 minutes.  Would that explain things?   I find it hard to read your configurations.